# How to disable bootstrap controls from code behind

Tags: asp.net, code-behind

i have a aspx page:

```
<div class="form-vertical">
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="ddlLocation" CssClass="form-control required" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="location_name" DataValueField="location_id" OnInit="ddllocation_Init">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="Select location..">
                    </asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-success pull-center"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Add</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>

....
Some more content here that needs to be displayed.
```

Based on certain conditions, when the asp.net page loads, I'd like to either
hide the entire div class="form-vertical"
OR
disable all controls

Can disable asp.net controls but how to disable button - btnAdd

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Hide `Div`: Give the div `id` and add `runat="server"` so that you can access the corresponding div from code-behind.

```
<div ID="myDivId" runat="server" >
  //div content
</div>
```

In code-behind set its `visible` property to `false`.

```
myDivId.Visible = false
```

To Disable `Button`: Add `runat="server"`.

```
<button id="myBtn" runat="server"> clickMe </button>
```

In code-behind

```
 myBtn.Disabled = true;
```